# Why do isotropic spaces deserve their name?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, definition, intuition, quadratic-forms

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_quadratic_form) defines a quadratic form to be isotropic if it evaluates to zero at some vector. What does this have to do with isotropy in physics i.e uniformity in all directions?

From my experience so far, mathematicians are very good at naming things, so what is the geometric justification for this definition?

Comment: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropy) also admits, that "isotropic" can have very different meanings, not really related to " uniformity in all orientations".